# Alternative history story from late 70's-early 80s relating to British victory in the American Revolution

Tags: story-identification, parallel-universe, alternate-history

Does anyone know the title and author of an alternative history from the late 70s-80s with a plot based on a scenario of British victory in the Revolutionary War?  I recall a scene which took place in what is now Washington D.C. describing the entrance to the Dupont Circle Metro.  It might have been a short story published in Analog or Galaxy.

Comment: What made this a parallel universe/alternate history? Can you [edit] to explain?

Comment: The plot was based on a scenario of British victory in the Revolutionary War.

Comment: This is pretty vague. There's literally thousands of alternate history stories about America losing the Revolution

Comment: There's a whole novel by Harry Harrison, called _[Tunnel through the Deeps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunnel_Through_the_Deeps)_, aka _A Transatlantic Tunnel, Hurrah!_

Comment: I don't think it was the Revolutionary War -- there would be no Washington DC and no Dupont Circle. However, I think there may be a story where Britain reconquered North America.  There's a recent series where the Civil War is still raging as a proxy war between European powers.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll check out the Harry Harrison book.

Comment: And the Sobel book as well.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly:  1973's For Want of a Nail by Robert N. Sobel?

Points that match:

> Does anyone know the title and author of an alternative history from the late 70s-80s

Partial Match: A bit earlier than you noted, 1973. But relatively close.

> with a plot based on a scenario of British victory in the Revolutionary War?

Match: the American Revolution failed and the British colonies become the Confederation of North America (CNA), while the defeated rebels go into exile in Spanish Tejas, eventually founding the United States of Mexico (USM).

> I recall a scene which took place in what is now Washington D.C. describing the entrance to the Dupont Circle Metro.

Partial Match:  IIRC, there is an analog city built where D.C. is today. (a bit of an irony since Washington D.C. primarily exists today because we did win the war).   I don't remember the exact scene you are mentioning. But, what you noted could be in it.

> It might have been a short story published in Analog or Galaxy

No Match.  This was a full novel.

Answer (score 0):

Harry Harrison's novel *[Tunnel through the Deeps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunnel_Through_the_Deeps)*, aka *A Transatlantic Tunnel, Hurrah!* was serialized in *Analog* in 1972.  The whole point of building the tunnel was to unite Britain with the fractious colony who had a rebellion two centuries or so ago but that was put down, and its leader executed.

There is no Washington DC (who would name a city after a traitor?) but Georgetown, Maryland may have had this "Dupont Circle".

Comment: There is no mention of the Dupont Circle in *A Transatlantic Tunnel, Hurrah!*

Comment: @JohnRennie What, is there a fulltext to search? I had to go upstairs and dig in a box.

Comment: Yes, a lot of the classics have been digitised by enthusiasts.

Comment: @JohnRennie well, back in the box it goes, then.